# Missing required parameters for roots in laravel app console

Tags: java, php, mysql, view, parameters

Hi there i am new to laravel  I am getting this following error when I click on fee group i get following error in my app can somebody help me here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is showing the missing parameter of student ID. Maybe you are trying to access a view without ID.

Comment: Hey there duetian ...can you guide me on skype as I m beginner on this